# Purescript Simple JSON, combining record types

Tags: json, purescript

I'm new to Purescript and attempting to use purescript-simple-json to:

1. Take some JSON and convert it into a record of `User`
2. Take some more JSON and convert it into an array of record of `Comment`
3. Take the result of 2. and put it into the `comments` field of the user record generated from 1.

Below is my attempt at this:

```
module Test where

import Prelude

import Data.Either (Either)
import Data.Foreign (ForeignError)
import Data.Generic.Rep as Rep
import Data.Generic.Rep.Show (genericShow)
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmptyList)
import Simple.JSON (class ReadForeign, readJSON)

newtype Comment = Comment
  { rating :: Int
  , username :: String
  }

newtype User = User
  { username :: String
  , comments :: Array Comment
  }

derive instance repGenericUser :: Rep.Generic User _
instance showUser :: Show User where show = genericShow

derive instance repGenericComment :: Rep.Generic Comment _
instance showComment :: Show Comment where show = genericShow

derive newtype instance rfUser :: ReadForeign User
derive newtype instance rfComment :: ReadForeign Comment

parseU :: String -> Either (NonEmptyList ForeignError) User
parseU xs = readJSON xs

parseC :: String -> Either (NonEmptyList ForeignError) Comment
parseC xs = readJSON xs

addComments :: User -> Array Comment -> User
addComments (User u) cs = u { comments = cs }
```

However, when I attempt to load this up in the REPL with `pulp repl`, I get the following error message:

```
Compiling Test
Error found:
in module Test
at src/test.purs line 39, column 1 - line 39, column 45

  Could not match type

    { comments :: Array Comment
    , username :: String       
    }                          

  with type

    User


while checking that type { comments :: Array Comment
                         | t0                       
                         }                          
  is at least as general as type User
while checking that expression $0 { comments = cs
                                  }              
  has type User
in value declaration addComments

where t0 is an unknown type
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this error message. I could remove the type signature for `addComments`, but the inferred type then becomes the same as the unnamed record in the error message above, which isn't the desired outcome. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much for having a look at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are nearly there. The error is telling you that you are returning "unwrapped" record instead of a `User` value.
Try to add the `User` constructor in the last function:

```
addComments :: User -> Array Comment -> User
addComments (User u) cs = User $ u { comments = cs }
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks very much for your help.